# iPod 3g 4.3.5 Updated Firmware Apps can't run

Tags: ios, applications

I have installed Firmware update to 4.3.5 for my iPod touch 3g (32gb), and after installation, I have a problem where apps can't run. I tap on an app, it runs (~1 sec) and then skips to main menu of iPod.

What it can be? What I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Try go to AppStore and update or download something free; the point is to authorize with apple store. Once you finish this, everything should be back to normal.